# Restrict JavaFX stage resize with root's minimal and maximal sizes

Tags: javafx, resize, window

I have a resizable stage with flexible layout. I'd like to prevent stage width and height from reducing below minimal width and height of corresponding root node.

I've searched over this site and found several suggestions to bind stages `minWidth` and `minHeight` properties to `minWidth` and `minHeight` properties of the root node. But `Region`'s `minWidth` property is not a value of minimal width but policy for computing it. Most times it is set to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` and so actual minimal width is computed each layout pass. How can I bind actual computed minimal width and height to corresponding stage properties?